# Error when trying to deploy functions on Google Cloud Platform for API.ai webhook

Tags: terminal, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I've been following [this](https://api.ai/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation) tutorial in order to deploy a function that will act as a Webhook for my API.ai bot and for the life of me I cannot deploy the function :

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttp --stage-bucket [BUCKET_NAME] --trigger-http
```

I did try different variations of this :

```
gcloud beta functions deploy weather --stage-bucket staging.weather-abc12.appspot.com --trigger-http
```

`helloHttp` : if I created an API.ai project that is called weather with a Google ID that is weather-abc12 which one should it be??

`--stage-bucket` : how is it supposed to look like? When I go to Google Cloud Storage I found this : weather-abc12.appspot.com

Then the `index.js` file I pasted from the link above has the function named helloHttp so I changed that to weather, weather-abc12 (tried a lot of things...) then I get this in Terminal :

```
(gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load   error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named weather
```

My problem is similar to another one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853355/gcloud-deploy-function-error-code-3/46070070#46070070) which did not get any answers unfortunateley.

Answer (score 3):

It is working now! I was actually editing the wrong index.js file  which is why even though I changed the function name the terminal would keep saying it doesnt match. My bad!